# Wrong MANIFEST.MF in war file

Tags: maven, manifest, war

I have pack jsp file to war using command "maven compile war:war". When i deploy it on JBoss SA i got view like this:

```
PK«µgG    META-INF/þÊPKPK«µgGMETA-INF/MANIFEST.MFóMÌËLK-.Ñ K-*ÎÌÏ³R0Ô3àår.JM,IMÑuª   XèÄ›˜*hø%&ç¤*8çä%–•kòrñrPK©ÆÐCDPK fµgGWEB-INF/PK1µgGWEB-INF/web.xml•‘QKÃ0…ßÿCÈ{’n}‘’v2Ì'}Ys·f¤iÙÍ–úïÕ©æêë9ß!'çÊYW[r„=šÆåtÂJÀ•6n›Ó§Ç9»¡³âúJX3Õ¶$â³MN+ïÛLˆ)oö[1M’‰x¹_>”ÔŠ‡^¹èGê+±SGÅñàxÙÔ"ZÂa¯Á;‰&Ã>¾lJåûVcä"!>û¯ÒUÂ;Ô”ÓgXßFmqG¿'HãñÃ„Hm°µê•9UCóS)R°ñ1`cYƒ¾—…q:^ùÚJ10þ„G³;lG°6ê`ýØ?ðÐãªœã†ÒiOyº^ñPK;¤ÙŸ¯PK«µgG    META-INF/þÊPK«µgG©ÆÐCD=META-INF/MANIFEST.MFPK fµgGÂWEB-INF/PK1µgG;¤ÙŸ¯èWEB-INF/web.xmlPKð%
```

Then same files from eclipse compile fine, but i cant use eclipse at this project. Maven is not adding my manifest.mf, is it my problem?

from maven:

```
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
```

Comment: Juste do mvn clean install, why war:war?

Comment: package return same result - dont adding manifest.

Comment: Which Maven version? Which version of maven-war-plugin? How does you r pom file look like and have you defined correctly encoding in your pom? What kind of file system do yo use?

Comment: sloved. i have to create maven project with -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp and jsp works fine, even without editing manifest.